# 2D map with Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am learning Java Streams and want to replace the below code with java 8 features.

I have a list of points with X and Y coordinates and a direction arrow:

```
final List<PathStep> path;
```

and I want to convert the above list to a map of maps like in the following Java 7 code:

```
    final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Direction>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (final PathStep pathStep : path) {
        final Coordinate coordinate = pathStep.getCoordinate();
        final int y = coordinate.getY();

        if (!map.containsKey(y)) {
            map.put(y, new HashMap<>());
        }

        final Map<Integer, Direction> mapY = map.get(y);
        mapY.put(coordinate.getX(), pathStep.getDirection());
    }
```

I was able to use stream.filter() and stream.map features, but I could not replace the above code with java 8 features.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Whilst this isn't a *typical* valid question as you've provided no attempt to write this with `streams`, someone will most likely answer it for you.

Comment: What good would it be to litter my question with a failed attempt just to prove I really have spent hours trying to figure out a way? I ended up with a map (y -> coords) while I wanted a map of a map (y -> (x -> direction))...

Comment: I'm just pointing it out. Usually how this site works is: you provide your attempt and the SO members will point out where you went wrong, or hint (or otherwise) towards how to rectify it.

Comment: The point of asking you to present your attempt, @PetrSládek, is (at least) twofold: (i) to deter people who really didn't spend any significant time trying to solve the problem for themselves, and (ii) to enable us to give you better-targeted feedback.  Sometimes it also helps clarify what is being asked, though in your particular case there does not seem to be any uncertainty in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect with `groupingBy()` and a nested `toMap()`. Assuming `path` is a `Collection<PathStep>`:

```
final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Direction>> map = path.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                step -> step.getCoordinate().getY(),
                Collectors.toMap(
                        step -> step.getCoordinate().getX(),
                        step -> step.getDirection())));
```

Comment: This is what I needed! The `toMap` in a `groupingBy` worked like magic! I did not know I can use it like that. Only just a note that I added a method reference `PathStep::getDirection` instead of the `step.getDirection()`. Thank you very much!